# How to read clob data and return string using TCL

Tags: xml, tcl, clob

How to read a clob data using tcl?

My function should read clob data and return a string in xml format.

Note: Table has 2 fields (Id, Image(clob))

Can any one help to resolve this prob?

I tried many option but got error like:

```
500 Status line too long (limit is 8192) at /usr/lib/perl5/wayport/wprpc.pm line 125
```

and

```
nsoracle.c:2170:OracleLobSelect: error in `OCIStmtExecute ()': ORA-03135: connection     lost contact
Process ID: 11519
Session ID: 878 Serial number: 31261
```

Comment: I see “`perl`” in that error message…

Comment: This is not a great question. You seem to be withholding many pertinent details, and providing tangential information ("[what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)" comes to mind) Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

> I see “perl” in that error message
>
> /usr/lib/perl5/wayport/wprpc.pm line 125
>
> LCC-00219: nested include file name is too large
>
> Cause: The limit on the size of a parameter file was exceeded. This limit is 8192 bytes.
>
> Action: Remove characters from the file to make it smaller, or use another level of nesting.

**References**

- [Oracle 8 Error Messages: LCC Messages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A64702_01/doc/server.805/a58312/newch5a4.htm)